# troubles authenticating StratosLive from Google Apps

Tags: wso2

Signed up for StratosLive via Google Apps. When I attempt to login, I am told "OpenID not accepted.OpenID authentication failed".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may or may not be related but I found this jira

```
https://wso2.org/jira/browse/STRATOS-993?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Aworklog-tabpanel
```

Exception occurs when login using Google Apps Account (Without SSO)

The resolution on the jira is "Won't Fix"

Seeing as how wso2 has a habit of slowly responding to our questions I figured I would at least assist you on some possible leads.

Comment: thanks. I just signed up directly without gapps and will call this answered. this other bug might be more relevant. https://wso2.org/jira/browse/STRATOS-1950